# Apple iOS and KRACK

Tags: mobile, vulnerability, ios, krack, apple

KRACK consist of several vulnerabilities (https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/228519). Apple released patches against CVE-2017-13077, CVE-2017-13078 and CVE-2017-13080 from what I could find in their patch release notes.

Are the rest of the CVE's not applicable to Apple iOS, or is iOS still vulnerable?

Comment: In [the paper](https://papers.mathyvanhoef.com/ccs2017.pdf) they claim iOS to not be vulnerable against most forms of the attack due to improper implementation (see the table on page 5). I didn't find a clear mapping from CVEs to attack classes mentioned in the paper though...